# How to set Google Groups moderation and posting permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

I have got the below script working for me.... (Script auto creates a google group with data from a spreadsheet that is auto populated with data from a form...)

```
function onFormSubmit() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17KZXpWHipISZSqgD9w255VrirzITrks0fLaBpXp7Ybk")
 var email = sheet.getRange("B"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValue()
 var name = sheet.getRange("C"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValue()
 var user = sheet.getRange("AH"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValue()
 try{
   AdminDirectory.Groups.insert(
     {
       "email": email,
       "name": name,
     }
   )
   AdminDirectory.Members.insert(
     {
       "email": user,
       "role": "OWNER",
     }
     , email)
   GmailApp.sendEmail("Manager@test.co.uk",email + "  Group creation | Success", " address has been created for " + name)
 } catch(e){}
}
```

Could someone help me finish it as the remaining steps that i cannot get working are:

Set Group Moderation settings to: Skip Moderation queue and Post messages to group

Set Posting permissions to: public

```
function onFormSubmit() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17KZXpWHipISZSqgD9w255VrirzITrks0fLaBpXp7Ybk")
 var email = sheet.getRange("B"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValue()
 var name = sheet.getRange("C"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValue()
 var user = sheet.getRange("AH"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValue()
 try{
   AdminDirectory.Groups.insert(
     {
       "email": email,
       "name": name,
     }
   )
   AdminDirectory.Members.insert(
     {
       "email": user,
       "role": "OWNER",
     }
    )
   AdminDirectory.Groups.update(
     {
       "whoCanJoin": "CAN_REQUEST_TO_JOIN",
       "whoCanViewMembership": "ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_VIEW",
       "whoCanViewGroup": "ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_VIEW",
       "whoCanInvite": "ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_INVITE",
       "allowExternalMembers": "false",
       "whoCanPostMessage": "PUBLIC",
     }
    )
   AdminDirectory.Groups.moderation(
     {
      "Spammessages": "Skip_the_moderation_queue_and_post_to_the_group"
     }
     , email)
   GmailApp.sendEmail("r.hershey@onemotion.co.uk",email + "  Group creation | Success", " address has been created for " + name)
 } catch(e){}
}
```

I tried this but either I'm tired or I'm missing something silly...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups), possible values for [`whoCanPostMessage`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#whoCanPostMessage) property are:

- **`ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_POST`** — Anyone in the account can post a message.
- **`ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST`** — Managers, including group owners, can post messages.
- **`ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_POST`** — Any group member can post a message.
- **`ANYONE_CAN_POST`** — Any Google Apps user outside your account can access your Google Groups service and post a message.
  **Tip**: When the `whoCanPostMessage` is set to `ANYONE_CAN_POST`, we recommend the `messageModerationLevel` property be set to `MODERATE_NON_MEMBERS` to protect the group from possible spam.
- **`NONE_CAN_POST`** — The group is disabled and archived. No one can post a message to this group.

  - When `archiveOnly value="false"`, updating the `whoCanPostMessage` property to `NONE_CAN_POST`, results in an error.
  - If `archiveOnly` is reverted from `"true"` to `"false"`, the `whoCanPostMessages` property is set to `ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST`.

Also, I don't see any references regarding `AdminDirectory.Groups.moderation`  and `Spammessages`. You may want to check the documentation given and see if [`messageModerationLevel`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#messageModerationLevel) and [`spamModerationLevel`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#spamModerationLevel) help.